# Show that two operators have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N \colon \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a nilpotent operator, show that $B + N$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues ​​for all $B\colon \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: False false false.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at $$ N=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ B=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Got it, I'm sorry. I think I got the question wrong. The original exercise says the following:
Let $N \colon \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a linear operator. Prove that $N$ is nilpotent if, and only if, it has only zero as an eigenvalue. Suppose that $N$ is nilpotent. Show that if $A$ is invertible and $AN = NA$ then $A + N$ is invertible. Conclude that $B + N$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, for all $B \colon \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$.
For me, according to this statement, $B$ did not need to be invertible or to switch with the nilpotent operator.A mistake